# Use current datetime as file path

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make my program copy a file and rename it using it's current name and the current date. This is my current code, I know it's not working, but at least it shows what I want to do. I get an error at `File.Copy...` saying that
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in    mscorlib.dll`

```
var DAT = DateTime.Today;
string DATE = Convert.ToString(DAT);
File.Copy("D:/folder/file.json", "D:/folder/file" + DATE + ".json");
```

Comment: Did you try to take a look at what `Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today)` produces? `3/6/2016 12:00:00 AM` in a US locale. Oh, and the `:` character is disallowed in file paths, except for the drive specifier.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Didn't think of that, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but it works.

```
string DAT = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(DAT);

        sb.Replace(" ", "_");
        sb.Replace(":", "_");

        var DATE = sb.ToString();

File.Copy("D:/folder/file.json", "D:/folder/file" + DATE + ".json");
```

You can also replace the stringbuilder and `String DAT...` with just

```
string DATE = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");.
```

Comment: `DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` (or whatever format you want)

Comment: I recommend removing Forward and Backward slashed, too.

Comment: @Joe but there won't be any forward or backward slashes in the name, right?

Comment: @EagL  That depends on whatever format the date string come in .  Based on what your setting are, you might see the date as 03-06-2016, or you might see it as 03/06/2016.

Comment: @EagL to avoid all possible invalid chars, take another look at KooKiz's comment.  Personally, I'd prefer filenames using the format  `YYYYMMdd` so that they would be sortable, but if you have multiple files per day, use `YYYYMMddHHmmss`

Comment: @Joe ok, I'll only have one file per day, but I'll keep this in mind if I ever make more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all invalid chars by getting them from [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Path.GetInvalidPathChars()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static class PathExt
{
    public static String ReplaceInvalidChars(String path, Char replacement = '_')
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            throw new ArgumentException(paramName: nameof(path), message: "Empty or null path");

        var invalidChars = new HashSet<Char>(Path
            .GetInvalidFileNameChars()
            .Concat(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()));

        return new String(path
            .Select(ch =>
                invalidChars.Contains(ch) ?
                    replacement : ch)
            .ToArray());
    }
}
```

...

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
var dateTimePath = PathExt.ReplaceInvalidChars(dateTime);
Console.WriteLine($"The time is {dateTime}");
Console.WriteLine($"The file is {dateTimePath}");
using (File.Create(dateTimePath))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File created");
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the help, but because neither the file copied nor the date added will have any invalid characters, I don't really understand what this code is for.

Comment: @EagL Are you sure? `var DAT = DateTime.Today;
string DATE = PathExt.RemoveInvalidChars(DAT.ToString());
File.Copy("D:/folder/file.json", "D:/folder/file" + DATE + ".json");` should solve your problem.

Comment: Well, not if I use my solution, and I don't really want to remove all of it. I want to replace it with something.

Comment: @Eagl Then you need something like the current edit.